# Pointer pointing to a different type

Tags: c++, c, pointers

A pointer stores the address of the variable it is pointing to. But why can't a pointer of one type point to the address of a variable of another type?

For example, why does the following code below give me an error?

```
int main()
{
   int *i;
   float a;
   i=&a;     //this statement gives me an error
}
```

Comment: How is the answer **not** in the title of the question?

Comment: Because `int*` is not the same as `float*`. If you want a generic pointer use `void*` (though I don't recommend it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802585/why-data-type-is-needed-in-pointer-declaration

This question explains why a pointer must have a type.

Comment: Keep in mind that an uninitialized variable being used leads to undefined behavior

Comment: the better question is, why do you expect this to **not** be an error?

Comment: C or C++? In this respect, they make a difference, AFAIK (I am not a C++ expert)

Comment: The pointer need to have the same data type as of the variable it is pointing to so that it knows the amount of data it need to read while dereferencing the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the `i` as integer and `a` as float.
if you point to a variable the data type should be same, You can point to a only if a is an integer variable.
change the data type of a as int and execute the program.
you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619135/why-pointers-variable-contains-address-of-same-data-type) link.
The pointers can point to any type if it is a void pointer.
but the void pointer cannot be dereferenced. only if the complier knows the data type of the pointer variable, it can dereference the pointer and perform the operations.

Answer (score 0):

In 32 bit machine., Normally address in four bytes. While the data type is declared then it pointing to that data type and taking the byte equal to the data type byte.

In this case I is a pointer to int. That means it will pointing to the four byte. Values can be stored in the integer format. While a is a floating point variable. So it will take the value stored in the floating format(It means exponent and mantissa). While accessing the pointer with different  data types. It  will dereference the value corresponding data type format.  So we get the some garbage value or some values enabled in the bits.

Answer (score -4):

Well, it is actually very funny, I was writing the code and got this kind of error, at that time I figured out the reason myself but then forgot and as soon as I posted the question the answer just came to me again.

In the above code `i` is a pointer variable of type integer which is assigned 4 bytes of memory **(though depends upon platform but for now lets just assume)** on the other hand float will be assigned 8 bytes of memory **(again just assumed)**. So if I make `i` point to the float variable it will lose the precision as it will only be able to contain the value stored in first two bytes only.

Comment: Don't think in bytes of memory chunks. Think about operations the compiler should compile when it derefenreces the pointer .

Comment: Size isn't what matters, it's the type. You don't get an implicit cast between pointers to different types, even if they have the same size.

Comment: I don't even see an attempt to answer OP's question here...

Comment: OP posted this answer to his own question

Comment: Better update your question with this information, as it isn't really an answer.